# Wanna show the all changes(overlap) of for loop plot in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, interactive

It is inquiry about Rshiny.
I created a function called foo as shown below.
In the function, there are 5 plots in the for loop. When you make a plot in Shiny, only the last plot is visible, and the remaining plots are not visible. Can not you see that five plots are being created (updated)?

```
foo <- function(iter = 5){
  for(j in 1:iter){
    plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col = j)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
}

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
sth 

 plotOutput('myplot')

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
sth ...

 output$myplot <- renderPlot({
     f <- foo(iter = 3)
    })  
 })

})
```

Comment: The plots are created dont worry, they are just not rendered to the client (as you overwriting them all the time), all plots must have unique IDs if you want to display multiple plots at the same time then assign IDs to them (e.g. plot1, plot2, plot3...). There is example here https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/ and many more for that matter

Comment: @PorkChop Thx, But what I wanted to do is that each plot seems to be overwritten and updated in one place... would you help me again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a loop here, because the server executes all of the code before rendering new output in the UI, and `Sys.sleep()` just causes the entire R process to stop for the specified amount of time. Instead, you can use `invalidateLater()` to make your plotting function trigger at set intervals of time, while still allowing the rest of the program to run normally.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sliderInput("iterations", "Iterations", 1, 10, 3),
  sliderInput("interval", "Interval (ms)", 100, 1000, 500, step = 100),
  actionButton("draw", "Draw"),

  plotOutput('myplot')

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  foo <- function(iterations = 5, interval = 500) {
    i <- 0
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      i <<- i + 1
      if (i < iterations)
        invalidateLater(interval)

      plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col = i)
    })
  }

  observeEvent(input$draw, foo(input$iterations, input$interval))

})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Now, you could also wrap this idea of doing something every interval into a sort of delayed `map` function, looking something like this:

```
map_later <- function(.x, .f, ..., .interval = 500) {
    i <- 0
    observe({
      i <<- i + 1
      if (i < length(.x))
        invalidateLater(.interval)
      .f(.x[i], ...)
    })
}
```

That would produce a neater and more easily manageable server:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  plotOutput('myplot')

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  map_later(1:5, function(i) {

    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col = i)
    })

  }, .interval = 500)

})

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Naming is probably not great here, but hey, it does what it's supposed to.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help!
My intention was to create a function that creates a function that draws a plot when a certain operation is finished, and then shiny it so that the user can see the effect of updating the view.
So I created a function with plot() in the for loop and tried to make use of it, but I do not know how to do...

Comment: I've edited the answer again, to perhaps better demonstrate the idea. The point is, you can't use a regular loop here, because that stops the server from rendering output. Instead, you can use a function that says: "Hey, go on doing what you do, but come back here in 500 ms"